# JWPlayer callback function is not getting executed

Tags: javascript, callback, jwplayer

In code shown below overlay function is not called.

```
 (function(jwplayer) {
       var overlay = function( player, config, div ) {
          console.log('hi');
       }

       jwplayer().registerPlugin( 'overlay','2.0', overlay );
 })(jwplayer);
```

Please help me with it. Also I am not recieving any errors on console.

Comment: Is registerPlugin API deprecated in JWPlayer 7. If yes, what is an alternative?

Comment: Can you also provide an example of your JW setup code - to show how you are associating the plugin with the specific player?

Comment: I have uploaded video on jwplayer and embed it on HTML page, like:
<script src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/playerid-videoid.js"></script>

Comment: You appear to be using the JW dashboard generated embed code - this doesn't actually provide a means to associate a plugin with a player (traditionally achieved via the "plugins" parameter) - so you either need to change to a custom embed where you can add the relevant code, or use an alternative technique to detect player creation and hook the events dynamically.

Comment: I have gone through one of the links: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/14594493-does-jw7-have-a-working-plugin-implementation- Its says plugin support is not there in jw7. I have also tried using jwplayer().setup({}) and with this also plugin is not called. Please let me know how can I embed video so that I can attach plugin.

Comment: It is resolved. Thanks. I was including downloaded Js file from net instead of copying Js file from my own jw player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jherrieven for guiding me. 
In order to add plugin to JW player. Below are the steps:

1. Sign up to jw player and include JS file from there in HTML file. Publish > Tools.

   [File to be included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCIUf.png)
2. Setup video and embed it in HTML page. Note here in jwplayer().setup() function we have added our plugin that we need to associate with our player.
    `<script>
         jwplayer("myDiv").setup({
             "file": "file.mp4",
             "image": "myImage.png",
             "height": 360,
             "width": 640,
             plugins: {
               'customPlugin.js': {
                   "key": "helloworld"
               }
             }
         });
   </script>`
3. Now in customPlugin.js file register your plugin.

   ```
   (function (jwplayer) {
       var pluginCallback = function(player, config, div) {
           console.log(config.key);
       };
      jwplayer().registerPlugin('customPlugin', '7.0', pluginCallback); })(jwplayer);
   ```
4. Output on console is helloworld.